# directus cms how to join

Tags: content-management-system, directus

I'm using directus for the first time. According to the documentation, database joins are possible. However, there is nothing about usage in the documentation, just a note to add this in future. Does anyone of you know how to use it anyway?

Answer (score 4):

You can setup a relational interface (like a many-to-one) to connect two collections. When that's setup you can use the `fields` parameter to select how many "levels" deep you want to retrieve the relational data.

Let's say you have a collection `books` and a collection `authors`. In this example, each book has a single author. Using a many-to-one interface in the `books` collection, you can now select what author wrote the book.

To fetch the books, you'd normally use `/items/books`. To retrieve the title of the book, and the name of the author, you can get `/items/books?fields=title,author.name`.

*If you want all the data, you can also use the `*` flag: `?fields=*.*` will retrieve all fields 2 'levels' deep.*